# Setting up an ADFS Proxy on custom Web Site?

Tags: proxy, iis-7.5, adfs

I ran some tests in dev with the ADFS Proxy and it worked beautifully. However, now that I'm in a more-rigid environment (a staging environment), I'm having difficulties setting up a proxy. The errors I get from the AD FS 2.0 Federation Server Proxy Configuration Wizard:

> The AD FS 2.0 Federation Server
>   Configuration Wizard requires either
>   (a) the Default Web Site to be present
>   in IIS or (b) only one Web site to be
>   present in IIS.

We don't meet either requirement. We have two web sites: 1) MVC (http/https) with a custom name and 2) WCF services (net.pipe/tcp). **Is there any way to specify a Web Site for the wizard to target?**

If I could simply tell it to install into our MVC's web site, all would be well. Otherwise, I'll have to tear down our WCF services' site to get this to install, which I REALLY don't want to tear it down and rebuild it afterwards. This seems like a ridiculous requirement and there SHOULD be a "Web Site Picker" for this wizard so I can tell it where to deploy. Do they REALLY think enterprises utilizing ADFS deploy their apps to "Default Web Site"? Really??

Comment: I think that they expect enterprises who deploy a system as complex as ADFS to have dedicated proxy environments available for use as the documentation stipulates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have simply renamed my target website to "Default Web Site", installed the proxy, then renamed it back. Pretty simple.

Is this really the best we have to do this? I can certainly imagine people NOT wanting to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The expectation is to deploy ADFS and proxies on machines that doesn't have any other websites or server roles on it.

Therefore, if you install ADFS on a new OS installation, it would use the default web site to publish its /adfs/ls virtual directory.

Good to see you have a workaround though. Please consider using the http://blogs.msdn.com/card (which is the product group blog) or https://connect.microsoft.com/ to offer feedback on the installer. The latter site has a project called "identity access management" which you can find in the connect directory. Else search "geneva" which was the codename and points to same project.